# GR Coordinate and proper time, null geodesic

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, geodesic, general-relativity, euler-lagrange-equation

I have a question which asks show that a null geodesic to get to r> R , r some constant, given the space time metric etc, takes infinite proper time but finite coordinate time.(question attached below)

I just want to confirm that, ofc there is no affine parameter for a null geodesic and so you could take coordinate time and proper time to be the same, and so that this question is referring to the time as observed by a timelike observer.

So if I denote the Lagrangian by L , you would proceed as follows :
1)set L=1 to find the relationship between proper time and coordinate time for the timelike observer ( only $\dot{t} \neq 0 $)
 since at rest to get proper time, all other coordinates 0 )
2) set L=0 solve for the relationship between r(t) and (t) - assume radial for simplicity and then
a) not substituting in the expression from 1) will give you coordinate time
b) substituting the expression in from 1) will give you the proper time.

Can I confirm these ideas are correct - basically the question does not specify, but it should be the proper time of a timelike observer ?

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: No, what you sate is not correct. The questions (part e) is a little confusing because of the nonstandard use if proper time. What is meant is affine parameter.

Comment: there is no proper definition of an affine parameter for a null geodesic though?

Comment: What do you mean? By definition it is a parameter for which the geodesic equation holds.

Comment: in my lecture notes we have the definition  of an affine parameter , s, is one in which dL\ds=0, where L is the Lagrangian of a freely falling particle and so for a null geodesic we always have L=0

Comment: That's true for timelike curves. In general a parametrization of a curve $\gamma(s)$ is affine if $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}=0$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation on the covariant derivative. Is this the geodesic equation written the covariant derivative way : V^u \nabla_v V^v = 0 ? This is four equations. Could I consider u= t equation to get an expression relating proper time  and coordinate time, where V= dx^u / ds

Comment: Doesn't your expression also need to be pre multiplieD by the tangent ?